# iOS Battery Data with React Native

Tags: swift, react-native

I am trying to access the battery information on the current device using both Swift and React.

I have `BatteryManager.swift` which contains

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(BatteryManager)
class BatteryManager: NSObject {

  @objc(getBatteryLevel)
  func getBatteryLevel() -> Float {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel;
  }

  @objc(getBatteryState)
  func getBatteryState() -> UIDeviceBatteryState {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryState
  }
}
```

I also have a `BatteryManager.m` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(BatteryManager, NSObject);

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getBatteryLevel)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getBatteryState)

@end
```

And I have my `BatteryManager-Bridging-Header.h` file

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

I then Clean and Build my project (not sure if necessary) and re-run `react-native run-ios` so that I start my React Native server and my iOS Simulator afresh.

I then import `NativeModules` via
`import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

I then write `console.log(NativeModules.BatteryManager)` - I **do** see my methods `getBatteryLevel` and `getBatteryStatus` although they both yield `undefined`.

I tried to run the console.log in a `setTimeout` but continued to get a value of `undefined`

Could anyone please help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`react-native-battery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-battery)? It seems like it's a module that accomplishes what you want. Alternatively, you can reference the Swift logic from [that project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/oojr/react-native-battery/tree/master/ios) if you want to try and adapt your solution (although that seems redundant to me).

Comment: Thanks for answering. The task isn't necessarily for just feeding Battery data, the task is to try and write some simple Swift and then utilise the code within React which is why I chose to write some simple battery related functions. Also isn't that `react-native-battery` code Objective-C? (I could be wrong)

Comment: @Munkie You could be right. I'm not at all a Swift or Objective-C expert, so can't really help you here. Good luck though.